# Excel Auto Number Cells

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a simple way to number cells down a column to a certain number?

For example, say I'm creating a table with 2 columns: "Trial Number" and "Result." If I know I have 5000 trials, can I get this to number itself out 1-5000 across each without having to number the first couple and dragging all the way down?

Comment: I think you need to create a routine for this where you input the number of trials and the destination range.

Answer (score 1):

Votes to close given lack of detail, but one way for anyone else trng somethong similar

```
Sub Populate()
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range

'starting cell
Set rng1 = [a1]
lngRow = Application.InputBox("Pls enter the amount of rows", "User Input", 5000, , , , , 2)
If lngRow > 0 Then
    With rng1
    .Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2) = Array("Trial Number", "result")
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(lngRow, 1).Formula = "=row() - " & rng1.Row
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(lngRow, 1).Value = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(lngRow, 1).Value
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.
Two inputs, 1st for the number then another for the output cell.

```
Sub generatenumber()

Dim rng As Range
Dim num As Long

On Error Resume Next
num = Application.InputBox("Enter max numbering", , , , , , , 2)
If Err.Number <> 0 Or num = 0 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select destination cell", , "$A$1", , , , , 8)
If Err.Number <> 0 Or rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

rng.Range("A1:A" & num).Formula = "=ROW(A1)"
rng.Range("A1:A" & num).Value = rng.Range("A1:A" & num).Value

End Sub
```

If the user cancel any of the two(2) input box, the routine terminates.